# What theorems and definitions are true/false considering mutiple variable functions and differentiation.

Tags: real-analysis

...I mean compared to single variable functions. For example the two variable function doesn't have to be continuous to define the partial derivatives. But what about the "left and right hand derivative have to be the same to be differentiable at a given point" and other theorems?

Comment: Your question is very broad.

Comment: Well I don't expect one person to answer it. I just thought this section would be a good place for a collection of the above. Even a link is sufficent enough for me where it is described thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "left and right hand" limits or continuity make no sense unless you specify that you are taking about "parallel to the x-axis" or "parallel to the y-axis".  Also, while it is true that "a function does not have to be continuous to have **partial** derivatives" it is also true that a function has to be continuous (in a neighborhood of a point) to be **differentiable** (at that point).